# How to have FilterMode on, but editmode off for GridEX in C#

Tags: c#, gridex

I need rows to not be edited in my GridEX but, if I turn EditMode off, it doesn't allow you to 'Edit' the filter section at the top. GridEX rows don't have an edit option only the columns do, so is there some way to get around this? Will I have to just do eventhandler stuff as a workaround? If so, are there any particular ways that work well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the CurrentCellChanging event and then set AllowEdit to False

Answer (score 2):

Set the whole edit off with GridEX1.AllowEdit
Then turn EditMode on for each column. That way you can't edit the records, but can edit the filter

Comment: This is the correct answer. I don't know why one would want to write extra code for it.

Answer (score 0):

as the previously user said, in the CurrentCellChanged event:

GridEX1.AllowEdit = InheritableBoolean.False